# How to get top 10 from one column and sort by another column in hive?

Tags: sql, sorting, hadoop, hive

I want to find top 10 title with high number of user ids. So I used query like

`select title,count(userid) as users from combined_moviedata group by title order by users desc limit 10`

But i need to sort them based on title, I tried this query

`select title,count(userid) as users from combined_moviedata group by title order by users desc,title asc limit 10`

But it doesnot sort them. Merely returned same results. How to do this

Comment: It certainly does sort them.  It sorts them by the count of users, and then ***for rows where the count is the same*** it sorts by title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of a   `WITH` clause

```
with t AS 
( 

  select title,count(userid) as users from combined_moviedata
         group by title
  order by users desc limit 10
)
select * FROM t ORDER BY title ;
```

Comment: My only comment is that this does not deal with tied ranks.  *(What if the 10th and 11th placed titles have exactly the same number of rows?)*

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @KaushikNayak is very close to what I'd consider the "right" answer.

- At one level, work out what your top 10 records are
- At a ***different*** level, sort them by a different field

The only thing I'd say is that if the 10th and 11th most common titles are tied for the same count, they should generally also be included in the results.  This is a `RANK()`.

```
WITH
  ranked_titles AS
(
  SELECT
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)   frequency_rank,
    title
  FROM
    combined_moviedata
  GROUP BY
    title
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ranked_titles
WHERE
  frequency_rank <= 10
ORDER BY
  title
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7283c/1

Note that in the example linked, 12 rows are returned.  That is because 4 titles are all tied for the 9th most frequent, and it is actually impossible to determine which two should be selected in preference over the others.  In this case selecting 10 rows would normally be statistically incorrect.

```
title    frequency  frequency_rank

title06  2          9
title07  2          9
title08  2          9
title09  2          9
title10  3          6
title11  3          6
title12  3          6
title13  4          4
title14  4          4
title15  5          2
title16  5          2
title17  6          1
```

Comment: Thanks!! Rank() is pretty new to me. Now i got it.